# replacing squares with rectangles with same length but half height in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering if using `symbols()` function in BASE R, I could replace the squares in my plot below with rectangles of the same length but half height?

```
plot((8:14)*.1, rep(1, 7), cex = 4, pch = 0)

symbols(rep(1, 7), (8:14)*.1, rectangles = .5) ## Tried this with no success
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a whole matrix as the value of `rectangles`, not just a number. Also,  the default is to use the size in inches, but it would be better to use the units of the picture itself by specifying `inches=F`.

```
RECT = matrix(rep(c(0.04,0.02), each=7), ncol=2)
symbols((8:14)*.1, rep(1,7), rectangles=RECT, inches=F)
```

[image: Rectangles]

The variable that I called RECT specifies the sizes. It should be a matrix with two columns. The first column specifies the widths of the rectangles.  The second column specifies the heights.

Comment: Thanks very much, as I intend to use your solution for many plots, would you possibly let me how to obtain the width and height of the rectangles given the original plots squares?

Comment: Are you trying to mix some squares and some rectangles? If you want to do that, use `symbols` with the `squares` argument so that you can make the squares and rectangles be comparable.