# Converting squares to rectangles in R plot

Tags: r, function, plot

This question is a follow-up on an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120579/replacing-squares-with-rectangles-with-same-length-but-half-height-in-r-plot). My goal is to replace the squares (`pch = 22`) shown in a number of different plots with rectangles of the same width but half the height.

**I was wondering how I can obtain the length of the sides of the squares in each plot, in the first place?**

For example, for the plot below, I can visually (i.e., try and error) find the width and height of the squares to achieve my goal but is there a functional way to do this for any other plot without try and error?

```
x <- (8:14)*.1 ; y <- rep(1, 7)

plot(x, y, cex = 6.3, pch = 22)

width <- (x + .039) - (x - .039)  # `.039` obtained visually (i.e., try and error)!
height <- (y + .033) - (y - .033) # `.033` obtained visually (i.e., try and error)!

rec <- matrix(c(width, height/2), ncol = 2)

symbols(x, y, rectangles = rec, inches = F, add = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use the `pch=22` to generate a rectangle? It would probably make more sense to use `symbols(x,y,rectangles=...` to place rectangles centred around a particular set of points.

Comment: It would just be a total alternative so you can specify the size exactly. E.g. `x <- (8:14)*.1 ; y <- rep(1, 7);

plot(x, y, type="n");
symbols(x, y, rectangles=cbind(.039,.033)[rep(1,length(x)),], inches=FALSE)`

Comment: I have no idea really. I can only imagine the size of the `pch=` graphics are specified somewhere in the R source code, which could be mapped back to the scale used in the plot. If you are starting a plot from scratch though, I wouldn't be trying to combine pch and rectangles to make them overlap.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, so the reason I'm doing this is because if I use the squares they cover part of my plots. But rectangles won't. Also the `help` section was n't particularly helpful. But I appreciate it.